# Query for id needs integer parameter

Tags: android, eclipse, orm, ormlite

In the documentation the following is mentioned:

```
Account account = accountDao.queryForId("John Smith");
if (account == null) {
    // the name "John Smith" does not match any rows
}
```

But in Eclipse(android) i only see the option to pass an integer as parameter?
any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Dao` objects use generics to enforce the type of id is associated with your entity.  If you only see the option to pass an integer into `dao.queryForId(...)` then you probably, mistakenly, defined the dao like:

```
Dao<Account, Integer> accountDao = getDao(Account.class);
```

The first generic parameter specifies the type of the entity and the second generic parameter specifies the type of the ID field in that entity.  With the `Integer`, you will call `accountDao.queryForId(Integer)`.

As @Tomas mentioned, you need to define your DOA with something like:

```
Dao<Account, String> accountDao = getDao(Account.class);
```

Then you can query for `Account` by a `String` id:

```
Account account = accountDao.queryForId("John Smith");
```

Answer (score 3):

First you should define what entities ID is of String type:

```
@DatabaseTable()
public class Account {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String mFullName;
    ...
}
```

Then you should declare Dao object according to entity type ant its ID type. Now you can use queryForId with ID type of String:

```
Dao<Account, String> accountDao = getAccountDao();
Account account = accountDao.queryForId("John Smith");
if (account == null) {
    // the name "John Smith" does not match any rows
}
```